# formatting datetime from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to format `2014-03-27 00:53:31` to be: `03/27/2014` I have tried many solutions but none of which have worked. My most recent is explained in this question.

So the time is stored in database as a `datetime` like: `2014-03-27 00:53:31`

I call this by `$customer->last_login;`

Then I am trying to format this by doing the following:

```
$dt = $customer->last_login;
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what is a better solution to formatting this to display just the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$customer->last_login` is a string, you have to convert to a `DateTime` object first.

```
$dt = new DateTime($customer->last_login);
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: Okay, that worked but if it's saved in the database with a field type of `datetime` then why do I need to create that? Just trying to learn.

Comment: @user3367639 PHP won't convert the data depends on the column type of db, what you get is always string, you have to do the conversion in the php side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime($dt));`